# Call a javascript function of Chromecast Receiver Library with JSON parameter in Dart

Tags: dart, chromecast, json, dart2js

i have this JS function call:

```
 this.customMessageBus = castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus('urn:x-cast:mycastapp', cast.receiver.CastMessageBus.MessageType.JSON);

var errorMessage = {
                    action: 'ERROR_MESSAGE',
                    errorCode: 'code',
                    errorMessage: 'sometext'
                };

this.customMessageBus.broadcast(errorMessage);
```

in trying to write the corrispective in DART:

```
this.customMessageBus = castReceiverManager.callMethod("getCastMessageBus",
    [
      'urn:x-cast:mycastapp',
      'cast.receiver.CastMessageBus.MessageType.JSON'
    ]);
this.customMessageBus.callMethod("broadcast", ['{
                        action: 'ERROR_MESSAGE',
                        errorCode: 'code',
                        errorMessage: 'sometext'
                    }']);
```

But i take this exception:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Unexpected message type for JSON serialization in [null]
```

The MessageBus component is documented at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastMessageBus#constructor_1

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the API, in the JS example you're passing a Map/Object, and in Dart you're passing a string. What happens if you pass it a Dart Map instead? Or if that doesn't work, you could try constructing a JS Object with the appropriate fields and passing that.